# Indy/ssl cannot open file

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm trying to use ssl with Indy and keep getting the following error:

> Project MtApp.exe raised exception class EFOpenError with message 'Cannot open file "C:\Development\MyApp\Win64\Debug\㩃䑜癥汥灯敭瑮作浡牡屵汁呬楨杮即獹潬屧祓䱳杯楓屭祓䱳杯楓䍭湯潳敬坜湩㐶䑜扥杵浜剹潯䍴⹁数m". The system cannot find the file specified'.

It occurs in the `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas` file in the following function:

```
function by_Indy_unicode_file_ctrl(ctx: PX509_LOOKUP; cmd: TIdC_INT; const argc: PAnsiChar; argl: TIdC_LONG; out ret: PAnsiChar): TIdC_INT; cdecl;
```

The `argc` parameter appears to be passed in correctly. The IDE debugger shows it as `"C:\Development\MyApp\Win64\Debug\myRootCA.pem"`. The problem seems to be when it is cast as a `PWideChar` and assigned to a `String` variable:

```
X509_FILETYPE_PEM:
  begin
    // Note that typecasting an AnsiChar as a WideChar is normally a crazy
    // thing to do.  The thing is that the OpenSSL API is based on ASCII or
    // UTF8, not Unicode and we are writing this just for Unicode filenames.
    LFileName := PWideChar(argc);
    LOk := Ord(Indy_unicode_X509_load_cert_crl_file(ctx, LFileName, X509_FILETYPE_PEM) <> 0);
  end;
```

The `LFileName` variable is `㩃䑜癥汥灯敭瑮作浡牡屵汁呬楨杮即獹潬屧祓䱳杯楓屭祓䱳杯楓䍭湯潳敬坜湩㐶䑜扥杵浜剹潯䍴⹁数m` after the cast, causing a `FileNotFound` exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say which version of Delphi or Indy you are using.  But, the code you have shown is not the latest code that is currently in Indy.

What you have described was due to a regression bug that Embarcadero introduced in the Indy release that shipped in RAD Studio 10.3. They fixed that in a patch for RAD Studio 10.3.3:

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-10-3-3-indy-server-ssl-certificate-patch/

https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30906

I suggest you update to the latest version of Indy from its GitHub repo:

https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/

https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy